# USB Camera Emulation for Windows 8

Tags: gratis, windows-8, usb, webcam, emulator

I develop a program accessing a USB camera using Windows 8. Unfortunately, my development PC has no camera.

Is there a (free) software that emulates an USB camera?

---

For sure there are many solutions and workarounds depending on hardware. Due to multiple reasons and constraints I'm looking for a software solution.

If there is a need to discuss why, this should be done on SRSE Meta. Feel free to open a discussion.

Comment: Why not spend the usually small amount of money to buy a USB Camera - got to be better than emulation. I see them starting from £2.00!

Comment: Sure, nice solution. I would like to work on the code asap but won't be able to get to a store during the opening hours - and I don't have a 3D printer :)

Comment: Amazon/ebay/maplin/etc have online stores. Unfortunately affordable 3D printers can't manage working electronics, yet! Some phones can even be connected as webcams.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Nevertheless, I stick to my question and updated it accordingly.